# VB.net Form Not Responding

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, chat

i am creating a program that can wait for computer to connect in my server
this code is initially implemented in console, but i want it in GUI form

```
MsgBox("Server is ready!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "ChatApp! | Alert")
    server = New TcpListener(ipendpoint)
    server.Start()

    While True
        client = server.AcceptTcpClient

        Dim c As New Connection
        c.stream = client.GetStream
        c.streamr = New StreamReader(c.stream)
        c.streamw = New StreamWriter(c.stream)

        c.hostname = c.streamr.ReadLine

        list.Add(c)
        FlatListBox1.AddItem(c.hostname)
        ListView1.Items.Add(c.hostname & " is connected")

        Dim t As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf ListenToConnection)
        t.Start(c)
    End While

    Me.Show()
```

after adding this to the Form_load but my form is not clickable or else
please help me this code work in background while my form is running

**EDIT**

I found an answer somewhere in google.

```
' Background work
Task.Factory.StartNew(Function() 

' Update UI thread

End Function).ContinueWith(Function(t) 

End Function, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())
```

but I dont know how to merge it to my codes

[image: error]
i got an error after adding this

```
If Me.InvokeRequired Then
Me.BeginInvoke(Sub() TextBox1.Text = "Done")
End If
```

Comment: Put your while loop in place of `Update UI thread` comment. Then _when you are actually_ going to update the UI you need to invoke the update if it's required. These two answers of mine shows examples of invocation: [Answer 1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35993139/3740093) - [Answer 2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34768375/3740093) - [Answer 3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35782000/3740093).

Comment: @VisualVincent I know the invocation but how I will invoke the "update UI"

Comment: I just gave you three of my answers with examples on how to invoke. What's the problem?

Comment: @VisualVincent yes I have red it but i got an error, see my post please

Comment: **1)** Use `ContinueWith(Function(t)...`. **2)** The updating should preferrably be inside `StartNew`. **3)** Please post the code too, not just a screenshot.

Comment: Sir, I just figure it out. Thankyou for your patience. I try to put it in StartNew. Thankyou so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form is not clickable because you are locking the UI thread.

You have a `While..End While` loop which never exits.

You need to either change this to exit at some point (the UI will be locked while it is running this loop), or move the code off of the UI thread if it needs to run more than once.

There are a number of choices

- A background worker
- A timer
- A thread,
- Or  Task(of T)

I'd suggest looking at [Tasks and Continuations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321405(v=vs.110).aspx) as you will are taking the result of reading the stream and interacting with the UI thread (I.E. putting the text into a listbox.)

Comment: thankyou for your response. I already tried the TIMER but its not working

Comment: I red about your recommendation about Tasks and Continuations and I was like -_- sorry. I think the explanation in website is a bit complex for me.

Comment: @something : How about you Google it yourself? There are alot of websites/forums that shows you how to use tasks, timers, threads, etc.

Comment: @VisualVincent i found one but I dont how to use it see my EDIT post